# Javascript SVG collision detection based on color within svg image

Tags: javascript, html, svg, colors, collision-detection

I am making a game where the player character moves around a grid that is an SVG image. I cannot find how to determine if the coordinates the character will move to will be a color that does not allow movement.

The movement itself works just fine and as expected, I just cannot figure out how to check the color or if there is another way to detect collision on a single SVG image.

Here is the SVG in the HTML file:

```
<svg width="600" height="580">
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="ViewBox">
<image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="doodmap.svg"></image>
<image x="40" y="40" width="18" height="18" xlink:href="Mage.svg"id="PlayerSprite"/>     
</svg>
</svg>
```

Here is my movement function in the javascript file:

```
function downmove(){
if(playerstats.position.y < 580){
        playerstats.position.y += 20;
        viewboxy += 20;
        document.getElementById("PlayerSprite").setAttribute("y", playerstats.position.y);
        document.getElementById("ViewBox").setAttribute("viewBox", viewboxx + " " + viewboxy + " 100 100");
        PMove();
    }
}
```

What I expect is to be able to detect what color the next square is and only move if the next square is not a certain color.

Comment: have the grid inline as separate objects then see what object you're going to move onto.

Comment: I have added the grid as inline and had the idea to add an ID to each cell in the grid. The problem I now face is that I am unable to refer to the IDs of the cells. I tried giving the svg that contains the grid an ID, but I cannot figure out how to refer to the IDs within the contentDocument.

Comment: Edit your question to show what you're now doing so we can help you.